# Emotion noun "from" an event/another noun

Tags: word-usage

I'm having some trouble with the use of "from" in constructions like "pride from the victory" or "happiness from the achieved goal". I'm not a native speaker and I can't figure out another way to word these nor can I seem to find an effective way to search for this particular issue. Edit to add: is "from" actually used correctly in these examples?

Comment: When you say you're "having some trouble" with those constructions, do you mean that when you read them you don't understand what they mean or do you mean you don't know how to use them yourself?

Comment: I understand what they mean but I would avoid them both in speech and in writing  because they feel unusual despite the simplicity of the words and concepts themselves. I am encountering them repeatedly in a book right now and I find it a bit odd that I can't pinpoint why they bug me. It's the first time I can't come up with an equally simple way to rephrase something. I guess I could say I'm getting "frustration from this issue".

Comment: Think of it as: "pride (derived) from the victory" or "happiness (derived) from the achieved goal" i.e., the pride/ happiness one **got** from victory/achievement. HTH.

Comment: _Pride in_ is more idiomatic than _pride from_.  See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pride